# Webrequest and webresponse

Tags: c#

I am using webrequest and webresponse in my application. I want to click on a button same as webbrowser control and fill a textbox field. How can I do this from webrequest and webresponse?

Comment: Please specify if the button you want to click calls javascript function when clicked, or it is just submit button.

Answer (score -1):

You cant do that, they just return you the response stream..

Answer (score -1):

I did a blog post on how to programmatically log into a website(I used Twitter in my example).  This is basically what you want(filling in textboxes and submitting the information), if I understand your question correctly.

http://eclipsed4utoo.com/blog/log-website-programmatically/

Comment: @Eclipsed4utoo, Manish asked to do that using webrequest and webresponse classes, not using the webbrowser control...

Comment: @RameshVel , using the `WebBrowser` control makes it MUCH, MUCH, MUCH easier which is why I posted it.  I thought we are here to give the best solutions(in our opinions).  If he asked on how to correctly use `ArrayList` in .Net 3.5, should we show him how to use `ArrayList`, or show him how to use generic lists?  I would think we would post the generic list answer(if it fit into what he wanted to use the `ArrayList` for)

Comment: i accept ur solution is good.. but he clearly asked webrequest and webresponse. if u read his post carefully, u can understand that he s having a konwledge in webbrowser control and he asked different way of solving that ( i want to click on a button same as webbrowser control )... hope u got the point...